# geolocation not working in chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have used the following script in mozilla and chrome browser. In mozilla, its asking us whether to share location. But in chrome its not displaying anything.

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
} else {
    x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
}
}
function showPosition(position) {
x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +
"<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

Do you use Chrome50 ?
They removed GeoLocation support for non https Sites.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/geolocation-on-secure-contexts-only

Comment: Iam using  chrome v 59.0.3071.115 tryed with https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation. It not work

Comment: and do you have https or http?

Answer (score 0):

couple of things I have found can cause this problem.

The first is if the web page is being browsed to on a file system, rather than via a web server (eg, you're just opening a html page stored on your desktop via a browser directly, rather than having Apache/IIS serve it via http://localhost/*)

Sometimes however, just hosting it via localhost isn't enough and it still fails.
It seems that you often need a publicly hosted site for the script to work. Why this is, I don't know, but I can only assume the client side script actually depends on quite a bit of server/domain settings.

Finally, sometimes be solved by enabling high accuracy (see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition), but the reason this sometimes does work, I am unsure.